# How to use ant unjar file from a jar into a specific directory without path from jar

Tags: ant, filepath, unzip, unjar

I want to copy files from within a jar to a specific directory *without preserving the path in the jar*.

I can use unjar to find just the files I want from the jar OK:

```
<unjar dest="some_dest_path" overwrite="true" src="somejar.jar">
    <patternset>
        <include name="somepath_in_jar/somefile.ext" />
    </patternset>
</unjar>
```

but the `somefile` gets extracted to:

```
some_dest_path/somepath_in_jar/somefile.ext
```

when I want the file to get extracted to:

```
some_dest_path/somefile.ext
```

ie without dragging the path it was packaged with along with the process

How can I extract a file from a jar without having the extracted file include the path it was packaged with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a mapper

```
<unjar dest="some_dest_path" overwrite="true" src="somejar.jar">
  <patternset>
    <include name="somepath_in_jar/somefile.ext" />
  </patternset>
  <mapper type="flatten"/>
</unjar>
```

see [ant mapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html)